# Matching redirect on url end, ignoring the substring

Tags: regex, url, redirect

Im currently trying to redirect from and old website to the new one.
The domain has changed and the subpath has changed, but the end is always the same, so I am trying to create a regex that will ignore the subpath, and only match with the ending, no matter what the combination might be.

Example:

http://shop.kmsport.dk/team-sport/bolde/fodbolde

https://kmsport.dk/collections/fodbolde

http://shop.kmsport.dk/fodbolde/fodbold-udstryr/anforerbind-325

These 3 urls all contain the word "fodbolde" but I only wanna match up the first two, since they both end on "/fodbolde", and ignoring the subpath in the process.

So far I've been able to match up the ends with this:

```
\/([a-zA-Z]*)*+$
```

How do I create something to account for the different subpaths?

P.s Its a massive sporting good store, so would be nice not having to creating a unique redirect for every possible combination -.-

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. If the question is *check if the letters between the end of the string and the previous slash are matching in two different string*, just use `\/[a-zA-Z]*$` on each string and check if `==`

Comment: Its a massive sporting goods store, with many products. Many different url paths and combinations. Instead of redirecting product-by-product and category-by-category, how could I do this more easily?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the last part just go with

```
url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
```

Comment: New to programming, still learning. This is python, correct? How would I redirect with this? (could you give an exampel with my urls above?)
also thanks for the answer

Comment: This remves the last part even if it is not `fodbolde`

Comment: Please rephrase your question!! Now I am confused as what are you looking for!!

Comment: I need to redirect many url's, not knowing the exact path every time, but only knowing the ending...

Comment: the above code is in python and it will capture the last part of your url. So, whatever you are doing with regex will be handled by this code and it will take care of the  urls where "fodbole" which comes in between!

Answer (score 0):

You current regex is not taking `/fodbolde` into account. If that has to be at the end you could use `$` to assert the end of the string like `/fodbolde$`

One possibility could be to match the start of the string `^https?://` and optionally match shop. `(?:shop\.)?` followed by `kmsport\.sk/`

Then use a repeating pattern matching not a forward slash followed by a forward slash zero or more times `(?:[^/]+/)*` and at the end of the string match fodbolde `fodbolde$`

[`^https?://(?:shop\.)?kmsport\.dk/(?:[^/]+/)*fodbolde$`](https://regex101.com/r/KjUZrT/1)

Comment: Ok this works pretty well, but it only matches specifically for the end "fodbolde".
Would it be possible to make a redirect where, what ever the end is, it will match with the url with the same path ending.
Eksampels:
http://shop.kmsport.dk/team-sport/bolde/fodbolde
https://kmsport.dk/collections/fodbolde
https://kmsport.dk/fodbolde/fodbold-udstryr/anforerbind
https://kmsport.dk/product/anforerbind

Comment: @EsbenHornbøll You could repeat the part that matches a forward slash followed by matching not a forward slash until the end of the string 
 zero or more times `(?:/[^/]+)*` or if there has to be at least 1 sub then you could repeat it at least one time using the plus `(?:/[^/]+)+` for example [`^https?://(?:shop\.)?kmsport\.dk(?:/[^/]+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/KjUZrT/2)